# R: Dataframe Manipulation

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, aggregate, data-manipulation

I’ve the follow dataframe as shown below

| ID | COUNT OF STOCK | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 10 | 2000 |
| A1 | 20 | 2000 |
| A1 | 18 | 2000 |
| A1 | 15 | 2001 |
| A1 | 30 | 2001 |
| A2 | 35 | 2002 |
| A2 | 50 | 2001 |
| A2 | 10 | 2002 |
| A2 | 22 | 2002 |
| A3 | 11 | 2001 |
| A3 | 15 | 2001 |
| A3 | 28 | 2000 |

I would like change the dataframe to the one shown below by grouping ID and Year(which is then use to count the number of years from 2020) to find the sum of count of stock

| ID | Sum of COUNT OF STOCK | number of years from 2020 (2020-year) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 48 | 20 |
| A1 | 45 | 19 |
| A2 | 67 | 18 |
| A2 | 50 | 19 |
| A3 | 26 | 19 |
| A3 | 28 | 20 |

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward. To work with those verbose column names you will have to quote them though, which might be a challenge.

```r
dat %>% group_by( ID, YEAR ) %>%
    summarise(
        `Sum of COUNT OF STOCK` = sum( `COUNT OF STOCK` ),
        `number of years from 2020 (2020-year)` = 2020 - first(YEAR)
    ) %>% select( -YEAR )
```

Output:

```
  ID    `Sum of COUNT OF STOCK` `number of years from 2020 (2020-year)`
  <chr>                   <int>                                   <dbl>
1 A1                         48                                      20
2 A1                         45                                      19
3 A2                         50                                      19
4 A2                         67                                      18
5 A3                         28                                      20
6 A3                         26                                      19
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this.

```
df %>% group_by(D, number_of_years = 2020 - YEAR) %>%
  summarise(Sum_of_stock = sum(COUNT_OF_STOCK))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   D [3]
  D     number_of_years Sum_of_stock
  <chr>           <dbl>        <int>
1 A1                 19           45
2 A1                 20           48
3 A2                 18           67
4 A2                 19           50
5 A3                 19           26
6 A3                 20           28
```

data

```
df <- read.table(text = "D  COUNT_OF_STOCK  YEAR
A1  10  2000
A1  20  2000
A1  18  2000
A1  15  2001
A1  30  2001
A2  35  2002
A2  50  2001
A2  10  2002
A2  22  2002
A3  11  2001
A3  15  2001
A3  28  2000", header = T)
```